# JVM Getting the largest objects in the heap programmatically

Tags: java, jvm, profiling, heap-memory, profiler

How **programmatically** (from within the java application/agent) do I get a "live" summary of the largest objects in the heap (including their instances count and size)?

Similarly to what Profilers do.

For example, here is a screenshot from JProfiler:

[image: Live objects]

Usually I used to work with heap dumps in the cases where I really needed that, but now I would like to figure out how exactly profilers retrieve this kind of information from the running JVM without actually taking a heap dump.

Is it possible to get this kind of information by using the Java API? If its impossible what is the alternative in the native code? Code example would be the best for my needs, because this specific part of java universe is really new to me.

I kind of believe that if I was interested to find the information about some really specific classes I could use instrumentation or something, but here as far as I understand, it uses the sampling so there should be another way.

I'm currently using HotSpot VM running java 8 on linux, however the more "generic" solution I'll find - the better.

Comment: Java Flight Recorder exposes a streaming API.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/jfapi/why-use-jfr-api.html

Comment: Use Java's reflection mechanism(Class class) and its methods to get method names. get instance count normally and to get memory occupied, use total memory and related api to get total memory of all objects.. hope this helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no standard Java API for heap walking. However, there is a HotSpot-specific diagnostic command that can be invoked through JMX:

```
String histogram = (String) ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().invoke(
        new ObjectName("com.sun.management:type=DiagnosticCommand"),
        "gcClassHistogram",
        new Object[]{null},
        new String[]{"[Ljava.lang.String;"});
```

This will collect the class histogram and return the result as a single formatted `String`:

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:          3269         265080  [C
   2:          1052         119160  java.lang.Class
   3:           156          92456  [B
   4:          3247          77928  java.lang.String
   5:          1150          54104  [Ljava.lang.Object;
   6:           579          50952  java.lang.reflect.Method
   7:           292          21024  java.lang.reflect.Field
   8:           395          12640  java.util.HashMap$Node
                       ...
```

The contents is equivalent to the output of `jmap -histo` command.

The only *standard* API for heap walking is the native JVM TI [`IterateThroughHeap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jvmti.html#IterateThroughHeap) function, but it's not so easy to use, and it works much slower than the above diagnostic command.

Comment: ... and JVM TI can't be used by a JVM against itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrei and Stephen! I'll add that calling this MBean through JMX requires a flag `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions`. Does it have any known performance implications on the running process, meaning can I specify it for all our applications by default? Other than that, I'm happily accepting the answer. In addition I'm "digging deeper into the rabbit hole" and asked a follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67156225/jvm-getting-allocation-call-stacks-programmatically Maybe you can take a look please. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @MarkBramnik No, it does not require `UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions`. The performance impact is the stop-the-world JVM pause for the duration of the heap walking (the duration is proportional to the heap usage).